# How do I display a value in a Ctkinter frame class?

Tags: python-3.x, class, customtkinter

my first post here. Please help me. All I'm trying to do is display the word 'yay' in a Ctkentry widget in a Ctkframe.

I am getting this error: NameError: name 'word' is not defined. Did you mean: 'ord'?

```
import customtkinter as ctk

ctk.set_appearance_mode("dark")

class Frame1(ctk.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, master, word):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.name = ctk.CTkLabel(self, text="Name", fg_color="transparent")
        self.name.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")

        self.name_x = ctk.CTkEntry(self, width = 300, placeholder_text="")
        self.name_x.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="e")
        self.name_x.insert(word)
   
class App(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title("CRD Master")
        self.geometry("1000x650")
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.acc_no = ctk.CTkEntry(self, width = 60, placeholder_text="Acc. no.")
        self.acc_no.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")

        self.button = ctk.CTkButton(self, width = 60, text="get", command=self.button_callback)
        self.button.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="e")

        frame = Frame1(self, word)
        frame.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=(10, 0), sticky="nsw")

    def button_callback(self):
         word = "yay"    

app=App()
app.mainloop()
```

I have spent hours on this but cannot figure it out and the internet has no answers. Yes the error probably explains the problem but I still don't understand how to pass a value into a class and display the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `NameError: name 'word' is not defined. Did you mean: 'ord'?`

This error comes from line 31:

```
        frame = Frame1(self, word)
```

You haven't defined `word` anywhere in your code.

Maybe you are thinking that this function defines it:

```
def button_callback(self):
        word = "yay"
```

**But,**

1. The function isn't called until the button is pressed.
2. Even if something called the function earlier you would still get that error because you are defining it locally to the `button_callback` function.

---

Another thing to mention is that after you fix that error you would get another one:

```
    self.name_x.insert(word)
TypeError: CTkEntry.insert() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'
```

That is because the [`.insert()`](https://pythonexamples.org/python-tkinter-entry-insert-text/) function receives 2 arguments: `index` and `value`. You provided value in the index arg position, so the function didn't get any value.

You can fix that error like so:

```py
        self.name_x.insert('end', word)
```

---

## Edit

---

Here is a way you can fix your code:

```
class Frame1(ctk.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.word = ''

        self.name = ctk.CTkLabel(self, text="Name", fg_color="transparent")
        self.name.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")

        self.name_x = ctk.CTkEntry(self, width = 300, placeholder_text="")
        self.name_x.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="e")

    
    def replace_word(self, word):
        self.word = word
        self.name_x.delete("0", 'end') # delete the entry content
        self.name_x.insert("end", self.word) # add the word

   
class App(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title("CRD Master")
        self.geometry("1000x650")
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.acc_no = ctk.CTkEntry(self, width = 60, placeholder_text="Acc. no.")
        self.acc_no.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")

        self.button = ctk.CTkButton(self, width = 60, text="get", command=self.button_callback)
        self.button.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="e")

        self.frame = Frame1(self)
        self.frame.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=(10, 0), sticky="nsw")

    def button_callback(self):
        self.frame.replace_word("yay")
```

- I removed the `word` argument from `Frame1` `__init__` function because it wasn't necessary. If you do need it, you can change the following lines:

```py
class Frame1(ctk.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, master, word):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.word = word
    ...
```

And

```py
        self.frame = Frame1(self, '')
```

**In addition**, in the current implementation, you don't need `self.word`. If you want to get the content of the `entry` you can simply use `self.name_x.get()`.

Comment: Thanks for your help nokla, much appreciated.

Comment: @Quinten please look at the `Edit`

Comment: Thank you so much nokla, you really helped me. I now understand how this works better.

Comment: Please consider accepting my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I have used your advice but still have not succeeded in showing the word 'yay' in the entry widget in the ctkframe. I'm not getting errors or the desired result and there is no internet resource that shows how to output data to an entry widget in a ctk frame class, which should be a simple task.
Please please show me.

```
import customtkinter as ctk

ctk.set_appearance_mode("dark")

word = ""

class Frame1(ctk.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, master, word):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.word = word

        self.name = ctk.CTkLabel(self, text="Name", fg_color="transparent")
        self.name.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")

        self.name_x = ctk.CTkEntry(self, width = 300, placeholder_text="")
        self.name_x.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="e")
        self.name_x.insert("end", self.word)
   
class App(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title("CRD Master")
        self.geometry("1000x650")
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.acc_no = ctk.CTkEntry(self, width = 60, placeholder_text="Acc. no.")
        self.acc_no.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")

        self.button = ctk.CTkButton(self, width = 60, text="get", command=self.button_callback)
        self.button.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="e")

        frame = Frame1(self, word)
        frame.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=(10, 0), sticky="nsw")

    def button_callback(self):
        word = "yay" 
        # Frame1.frame(word)
        # print(word)

app=App()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: First, it is a bad practice to use global variables.

Comment: In addition, strings in python passed by value and not by reference